# How to access the host of another node from the inventory file?

Tags: ansible

I have an ansible inventory file which contains "nfsserver" and "clusternode" IPs. I am running the role for "nfsserver" and need to access the "clusternode" ip in "nfsserver" role. What is the command I can use?

I have tried `{{ hostvars["clusternode"] }}` but it didn't help. Tried `{{ hostvars.clusternode }}`, `{{ hostvars["clusternode"]["ipv4"]["address"] }}` and `{{ hostvars.clusternode.ipv4.address }}`. Nothing helped

host_inventory:

```
[clusternode]

192.168.125.21

[nfsserver]

192.168.125.22
```

expected: 192.168.125.21

actual:  The error was: \"hostvars['clusternode']\" is undefined

Comment: Your inventory is named `host_inventory.yml` but that's not a YAML file. That's going to be confusing.

Comment: Sorry I have corrected it. Please help me to get the clusternode ip in nfsserver role

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have tried {{ hostvars["clusternode"] }} but it didn't help.

There is no host named "clusternode".  There is a *group* named "clusternode", and you can get a list of group members from the `groups` dictionary, like this:

```
---
- debug:
    msg: "{{ groups.clusternode }}"
```

This would yield a list of the hosts in your "clusternode" group (which, given your inventory, will be a list of ip addresses). If you have more than one host in the "clusternode" group, you could use a `loop` to iterate over them.  If you have only a single node, you could get the address using `groups.clusternode.0`.

---

> Tried {{ hostvars.clusternode }}

That is identical to your first attempt: `variable.key` and `variable["key"]` both do the same thing in Jinja expressions.

> `{{ hostvars["clusternode"]["ipv4"]["address"] }}` and `{{ hostvars.clusternode.ipv4.address }}`

Since `hostvars["clusternode"]` doesn't exist, you would expect these to fail.